# Licensing ExtJs - Distribution of an app using ExtJs 4.2.0 is it allowed?

Tags: extjs

Is it allowed to sell an app that is built with the open-source ExtJS 4.2.0 to companies if they use the app to provide a free service or for intern uses only?

Edit:

From this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298989/1914034

If you respect one of those condition, you can, but does it apply if you sell it?

- You open-source your app under GPL v3.
- The app is only for internal use in your company.
- The app is used by your company to provide a service and not directly
  distributed to the customer e.g. most web pages (according    to GPL
  this is interpreted as an internal use of the app - if Ext    team
  would have chosen to prohibit that, then they would have used
  Affero GPL, which directly forbids that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can as long as you publish the project under GPL licence.

http://www.sencha.com/legal/open-source-faq/